# Testing the path module

Tags: path-aliases

Taxonomy terms on my site are saved with the proper path alias assigned to them but attempting to go to the corresponding page results in a "page not found" error.

The core path module includes a test file (path.test.) Does anyone know how to use it?
Thanks. :)

I welcome any suggestion on how to fix that problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running tests is fairly straight forward:

1. Enable the Testing module at /admin/modules
2. Visit /admin/config/development/testing and choose tests to run (you'll find Path, Path API and Pathauto)
3. Run them and wait for the results

If you have stable versions of core and the contrib modules it's a pretty safe bet that they'll pass.

Comment: Wow! I didn't even know about this module. It looks like Ubercart was the culprit. Thank you so much! :)